# Why maven should download description jar's pom first?

Tags: maven, jar, pom.xml

When I download a jar(through maven's pom.xml),it looks like that maven will download the jar's pom first(***.pom). Why? And if there arenot have the jar's pom,could I download jar and what is the jar's pom function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jar that you are download might have dependency on other jars. This information is present in the pom file of the jar.  Hence maven downloads the pom first.

maven will download the jar even if the pom is absent, but will give a warning.